# Is there any way to open files from Azure storage account in online office 365?

Tags: java, azure, logic, office365

I am creating an application where I do interaction with files in Azure storage account with java services. I want to open uploaded files in office 365 so that I can edit them. How I can do that?

Is there any reference code available for the same to do it with service from java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To view the Office files (Word, Excel, PowerPoint) in Office 365 online document viewer, you can create a link to your blob by using [`Online Doc Viewer`](https://products.office.com/en-us/office-online/view-office-documents-online) utility. Essentially the link that will be created will be:

`https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=<Encoded URL of Blob>`

Please note that:

- The documents you open through this utility will be opened in read-only mode. You won't be able to edit these documents unless you save those documents in One Drive.
- If the blob container containing the documents has private ACL, then you will need to create a `Shared Access Signature` with at least `Read` permission to view the documents.

Comment: Do you know for sure that this works with SAS urls from azure blob storage? I get file not found errors although the document comes down if opened directly and not via view.officeapps.live.com

Comment: is any documentation for editing the documents. Does creating the SAS with "Write" permission helps in editing?????